# Docker container's status started by docker-compose is always exited

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  test123:
    build: .
    container_name: "test123"
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

When I run:

```
docker run -it alpine:3.9
```

It works fine. But when I run from docker-compose:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

The container's status is always: `Exited (0)`

Any idea?

Comment: Add output of `docker ps -a` when you run both ways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container starts and exits immediately because `/bin/sh` stops. This is how containers work. When their `PID 1` stops, they exit. So, in order to prevent `sh` from exiting, you have to use:

```
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

These options are the equivalent `-it` that you already use in your `docker run ...` command.

> from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/edge/engine/reference/commandline/run/):
>
> ```
> --tty , -t                Allocate a pseudo-TTY
> --interactive , -i        Keep STDIN open even if not attached
> ```

---

Updated `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: "3"

services:
  test123:
    build: .
    container_name: "test123"
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

Answer (score 0):

No wonder your container exits (with status 0, which means `success`).
The container must keep running in order to stay alive, so the command that is run must never end. Here would be a workaround:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.9

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

That way the container will always remain busy, until you stop it.